# Client triggered Parse.com Push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, client, server-side

I am creating a simple forum app for ANDROID using Parse. I am stuck at a problem related to notifications

For instance I want that when user A posts a comment in a forum app, user B (who subscribed to that post) will receive a push notification, can I do that using either client code,  instead of handling it using Cloud Code, or the REST API?   If not then how to I start developing the server side to use cloud code or REST API

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users to send push notifications via the client is bad for security reasons. It's not incredibly difficult to get the application id and client key to an app. Anyone with that information will be able to create their own code that allows them to target whoever they want with push notifications if client push is enabled.

Comment: but how to do that please give me a link to the some tutorial or a snippet of code related to it cause I am trying hard for this.

Comment: have you looked at the guide on Parse.com? It's has all the info you need to know...